# Не получается вывести данные использую связку node+express+socket.io+angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io

app.js

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {'connection' которое создает  
io.connect(port);
 var name = 'U' + (socket.id).toString().substr(1,4); 
 var date;

con.then(function(res){
    socket.emit('allMessage', res);
});

socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', name);

socket.emit('userName', name);

socket.on('message',function(msg){
io.sockets.emit('messageToclient',msg,name);

  InData.insert(msg,name,"Sex");
});
 });
```

main.js

```
var SelectChat = angular.module('SelectChat', 
 ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'NameInfo'
});
}]).factory('socket',['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
var port = 8080;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:' + port);

return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, callback);
    },
    emit: function(eventName,data){
        socket.emit(eventName,data);
    }
}
}]);
SelectChat.controller('NameInfo',function($scope,socket){


socket.on('userName',function(userName){
$scope.name = userName;
});

socket.on('newUser',function(newUser){
$scope.newUsername = newUser;
});

socket.on('allMessage',function(date){

$scope.nameChat = date.rows.name;
console.log(date.rows.name + "<============");
})

socket.on('messageToclient',function(msg,name){

$scope.sengMsg = msg;
$scope.sendMsgUser = name;

})



})

$(document).on('click','button',function(){

var message = $('input').val();
socket.emit('message',message);
$('input').val(null);
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head ng-app="SelectChat">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>chat</title>
<script src="javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="javascripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Здесь можете подключить ваш main.css -->
  </head>

 <header>
<h1>Chat</h1>
</header>

 <body>
 <div ng-controller="NameInfo">
   <p ng-repeat="msg in nameChat">
      {{msg}}
   </p>
   <p>{{nameChat}}</p>
 </div>
</body>

 <footer>
<input type="text" name="text" size="100">
<button type="button" name="button" id="sendMsg">Отправить</button>
</footer>

</html>
```

Должен вывести данные с бд, но я получаю просто вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему у Вас `ng-app` находится в теге `head`?

Comment: Да верно заметил, буду решать дальше) спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [не работает биндинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918830/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3)