# не работает биндинг

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пытаюсь вывести данные на страницу, но нет никакой реакции, в console.log выводит,данные с сервера поулчаю.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>chat</title>
<script src="javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="javascripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Здесь можете подключить ваш main.css -->
</head>
<body ng-app="SelectChat" ng-controller="NameInfo as dash">
<header >
<h1>Chat</h1>
</header>

<main>
 <div>
   <p>Привет</p>
   <p>{{dash.nameChat}}/</p>
   <p><span ng-bind="nameChat">{{nameChat}}</span></p>
 </div>
</main>
<footer>
<input type="text" name="text" size="100">
<button type="button" name="button" id="sendMsg">Отправить</button>
</footer>
</body>
 </html>
```

main.js

```
var SelectChat = angular.module('SelectChat', 
['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'NameInfo'
});
}]).factory('socket',['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
var port = 8080;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:' + port);

return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, callback);
    },
    emit: function(eventName,data){
        socket.emit(eventName,data);
    }
 }
 }]);
 SelectChat.controller('NameInfo',function($scope,socket){


 socket.on('userName',function(userName){
 $scope.name = userName;
 });

 socket.on('newUser',function(newUser){
 $scope.newUsername = newUser;
 });

 socket.on('allMessage',function(date){

$scope.nameChat.nameChat = date.rows[0].nameChat;
console.log(date.rows[0].nameChat + "   <============");
})

socket.on('messageToclient',function(msg,name){

$scope.sengMsg = msg;
$scope.sendMsgUser = name;

})

$(document).on('click','button',function(){

    var message = $('input').val();
    socket.emit('message',message);
    $('input').val(null);
 });
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы используете `io`, который не является частью ангуляра. Соотвественно событие `on` происходит вне области видимости ангуляра, т.е. он не знает, что значение в модели (например `sengMsg`) изменилось.

Для исправления используйте метод [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

```
.factory('socket',['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
var port = 8080;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:' + port);

return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, ()=>{$rootScope.apply(callback)});
    },
    emit: function(eventName,data){
        socket.emit(eventName,data);
    }
 }
 }]);
```